# Need a counter example for series convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I need some advice for constructing a counter example for $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ converge but $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{a_i}{i}$ diverges.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What makes you think there's any?

Comment: Is this a homework question, or your conjecture?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what proposition you're attempting to prove/disprove. It might be clearer if you declare the proposition before saying whether you believe it true or false, include your reasoning, and ask for help where you need it.

Comment: I think there should be an counter-example as a_n is not absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no counterexample.

Take $t_n=\frac{1}{n}$ then $t_n$ is decreasing & positive with limit $0$. It is given that $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n$ converges. By [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) it follows that $\displaystyle \sum_{n\geq 1} a_n t_n$ converges.